# php drop down print selected item

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am trying to print the selected dropdwon item. I have already written the code for dropdown to fetch a column from database.

Now i should print the only the id of selcted dropdown item. i don't know how to make it. please help me, this is my code

```
<? 
$query_name="SELECT id_cat,name FROM `fs01_metier_cat` ORDER BY `fs01_metier_cat`.`name` ASC";
$result = mysql_query ($query_name);

echo "<select name=category value=''></option>";
while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<option value=$nt[name]>$nt[name]</option>";
}
echo "</select>";



$query_id="SELECT id_cat FROM `fs01_metier_cat`";
$result1 = mysql_query ($query_id);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
{
   echo $row['id_cat'];
}

?>
```

Comment: I don't see any HTML output. What have you tried?

Comment: I think you mean you want to change the content of the second dropdown if the first dropdown changes? If so, this is frequently asked, I would suggest to use the search and you will find many different descriptions how to do that.

Comment: use javascript. Or if you want to do it by PHP only, include `<form>` tag with action self and onchange of select dropdown, just submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<option value='{$nt['id_cat']}'>{$nt['name']}</option>";
}
```

with {} php can insert also array values into a string and you should set ' ' around the attribute "value"'s value (alot of values here.. ^^), that the html is w3c conform (i dont know if a browser would take it as correct without them..)

without the { } it would look like that:

```
while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='".$nt['id_cat']."'>".$nt['name']."</option>";
}
```

depending on your editor code highlighting might work better in the second case ;)

and about the selected item:

i would suggest you to use jQuery to get the content of the selected item

```
var selectedId = $('#yourselectid option:selected').attr('value');
```

and then you can e.g. write it to the document or to a div:

```
document.write(selectedId);
```

or

```
$('#yourDivIdWhereYouWantToPutTheSelectedId').html(selectedId);
```

**important:** please note that i changed the value's index to **id_cat** because then you can handle the options with their id

Since the selected option changes everytime you change the dropdown selection, you can not handle this via php. There are ways to do that without a huge library like jQuery (since they are also just simple Javascript) but they simplify such things alot ;)

Comment: Excuse me!I have tested with internet explorer and chrom. it prints the list in the dropdwon only. I would like to print it's 'id_cat' where the name(an item from dropdown) is selected.

Comment: For the case 2: it's nice list the item of one column in the dropdown menu.But it doesn't print the id_cat number after i have selected! thank you anyway!

Comment: Thank you for the Jquery suggestion! But i don't know where i have to keep the jquery library files! can i keep the jquery library files in the same location of my working file?

Comment: Well since jquery is just a javascript file, may i suggest you the w3schools homepage, you should be able to learn everything about how to include javascript and the lines i wrote above at this page ;) (and alot more..): [w3schools](http://w3schools.com/js/js_howto.asp) it is in general good page where you can learn all the basics about css, php, javascript, ajax, etc... btw, [here](http://w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp) you see how you can import js files into your page (you have to place the file in your web pages directory or in any subdirectory of that directory)